# How to disable trigger click after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

`onclick` of the `a` elements I need to call a function and trigger `#myDiv` only once. Assume I am clicking 'Apple' any number of times it should trigger only one time. Then go to 'Orange' or 'Banana' and come back to 'Apple' again as same as earlier I need to trigger only one time. Assume there can be any number of `a` and those are dynamic. How can I achieve this?

```js
function activateMyClick(myId) {
   $('#myDiv').trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a onclick="activateMyClick(7)" id="7" class="active">Apple</a>
<a onclick="activateMyClick(8)" id="8" class="active">Orange</a>
<a onclick="activateMyClick(9)" id="8" class="active">Banana</a>
```

Comment: very incomplete code, but you can toggle a class on `<a>` and check if it has that class and prevent click ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution but I think works as you describe.

- Multiple clicks on Apple, trigger fires only one time
- After clicking on other links and then click again on Apple, trigger fires again only one time

```js
var currentId = "";

function activateMyClick(myId) {
  if (currentId != myId) $('#myDiv').trigger('click');
  currentId = myId;
}

$('#myDiv').click(function() {
  console.log('div click raised!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="activateMyClick(7)" id="7" class="active">Apple</a>
<a onclick="activateMyClick(8)" id="8" class="active">Orange</a>
<a onclick="activateMyClick(9)" id="8" class="active">Banana</a>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

As you've tagged this with jQuery you could remove the outdated `on*` event attributes and use `one()` to achieve this:

```js
$('a.active').one('click', function() {
  $('#myDiv').trigger('click');
});

// for demonstration purposes only:
$('#myDiv').click(function() {
  console.log('div click raised!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="7" class="active">Apple</a>
<a id="8" class="active">Orange</a>
<a id="8" class="active">Banana</a>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: OP states that when he comes back to 'Apple' should work again as earlier, trigger only one time. Your fiddle doesn't seem to work this way.